# How to set focus/place caret to SearchBox

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I got this layout:

```
    <RelativePanel>
        <ButtonContent="&#xE700;" Name="btHumburger"/>
        <Button Content="&#xE0A6;" Name="btBack"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Home" Name="tbHeader"/>
        <Button Content="&#xE11A;" Name="btSearch"/>
        <SearchBox Visibility="Collapsed" Name="asbSearch" LostFocus="asbSearch_LostFocus"/>
    </RelativePanel>
```

And i want to display `SearchBox` only when i hit button `btSearch`, and hide it when focus is lost. In codebehind:

```
    private void btSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        asbSearch.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        asbSearch.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

        btHumburger.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        btBack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        tbHeader.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        btSearch.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void asbSearch_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        asbSearch.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        btHumburger.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btBack.Visibility = mainFrame.CanGoBack ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        tbHeader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        btSearch.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

But `asbSearch` dont get focused/placed caret after `asbSearch.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);`, so `LostFocus` event wont fire. How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `asbSearch.UpdateLayout();` before setting the focus.

It seems that the `Visibility` change is not fully finished and the control can't receive focus before that.